# Unable to create state store in Kafka streams

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I am getting this error `Failed to lock the state directory: /tmp/kafka-streams/string-monitor/0_1` while creating state store in my kafka streams application. Here is the complete stack trace of the application

```
[2016-08-30 12:43:09,408] ERROR [StreamThread-1] User provided listener org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread$1 for group string-monitor failed on partition assignment (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.ProcessorStateException: Error while creating the state manager
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AbstractTask.<init>(AbstractTask.java:71)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.<init>(StreamTask.java:86)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.createStreamTask(StreamThread.java:550)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.addStreamTasks(StreamThread.java:577)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.access$000(StreamThread.java:68)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread$1.onPartitionsAssigned(StreamThread.java:123)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.onJoinComplete(ConsumerCoordinator.java:222)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$1.onSuccess(AbstractCoordinator.java:232)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$1.onSuccess(AbstractCoordinator.java:227)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.fireSuccess(RequestFuture.java:133)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.complete(RequestFuture.java:107)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture$2.onSuccess(RequestFuture.java:182)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.fireSuccess(RequestFuture.java:133)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.complete(RequestFuture.java:107)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$SyncGroupResponseHandler.handle(AbstractCoordinator.java:436)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$SyncGroupResponseHandler.handle(AbstractCoordinator.java:422)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$CoordinatorResponseHandler.onSuccess(AbstractCoordinator.java:679)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$CoordinatorResponseHandler.onSuccess(AbstractCoordinator.java:658)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture$1.onSuccess(RequestFuture.java:167)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.fireSuccess(RequestFuture.java:133)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.complete(RequestFuture.java:107)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient$RequestFutureCompletionHandler.onComplete(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:426)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:278)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.clientPoll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:360)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:224)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:192)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:163)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureActiveGroup(AbstractCoordinator.java:243)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.ensurePartitionAssignment(ConsumerCoordinator.java:345)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:977)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:937)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:295)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:218)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to lock the state directory: /tmp/kafka-streams/string-monitor/0_1
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorStateManager.<init>(ProcessorStateManager.java:95)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AbstractTask.<init>(AbstractTask.java:69)
    ... 32 more
Exception in thread "StreamThread-1" org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Failed to rebalance
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:299)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:218)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.ProcessorStateException: Error while creating the state manager
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AbstractTask.<init>(AbstractTask.java:71)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.<init>(StreamTask.java:86)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.createStreamTask(StreamThread.java:550)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.addStreamTasks(StreamThread.java:577)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.access$000(StreamThread.java:68)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread$1.onPartitionsAssigned(StreamThread.java:123)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.onJoinComplete(ConsumerCoordinator.java:222)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$1.onSuccess(AbstractCoordinator.java:232)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$1.onSuccess(AbstractCoordinator.java:227)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.fireSuccess(RequestFuture.java:133)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.complete(RequestFuture.java:107)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture$2.onSuccess(RequestFuture.java:182)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.fireSuccess(RequestFuture.java:133)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.complete(RequestFuture.java:107)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$SyncGroupResponseHandler.handle(AbstractCoordinator.java:436)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$SyncGroupResponseHandler.handle(AbstractCoordinator.java:422)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$CoordinatorResponseHandler.onSuccess(AbstractCoordinator.java:679)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$CoordinatorResponseHandler.onSuccess(AbstractCoordinator.java:658)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture$1.onSuccess(RequestFuture.java:167)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.fireSuccess(RequestFuture.java:133)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.complete(RequestFuture.java:107)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient$RequestFutureCompletionHandler.onComplete(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:426)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:278)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.clientPoll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:360)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:224)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:192)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:163)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureActiveGroup(AbstractCoordinator.java:243)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.ensurePartitionAssignment(ConsumerCoordinator.java:345)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:977)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:937)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:295)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to lock the state directory: /tmp/kafka-streams/string-monitor/0_1
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorStateManager.<init>(ProcessorStateManager.java:95)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AbstractTask.<init>(AbstractTask.java:69)
    ... 32 more
```

And I create a state store as below

```
 StateStoreSupplier avgStore = Stores.create("avgStore")
          .withKeys(Serdes.String())
          .withValues(Serdes.String())
          .persistent()
          .build();
```

Any idea of how to fix this?

Comment: Do you have another instance with the same config running ? That might lock the directory.

Comment: Also, try: fuser /tmp/kafka-streams/string-monitor/0_1. It will list other processes using the file.

Comment: No other process is running and no other process is using that dir/file.

Comment: Did you try to delete the directory manually? Can you reproduce the issue? Your application ID is "string-monitor" ? Do you use `0.10.0.0` or `0.10.0.1` ?

Comment: Could this be the issue you are facing? https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-3752

Comment: @matthias-j-sax I tried manually deleting those log files but no success. Yes string-monitor is my app id. I use Kafka `0.10.0.0` which ships with `confluent-3.0.0-2.11`

Answer (score 4):

Did you configure multiple threads within your application instance? If yes, it may be due to a known issue in older versions of Kafka, where the underlying consumer used by Kafka Streams (in the app instance) can take too long to rebalance, causing itself to be kicked out of the consumer group (and hence triggering another consumer group rebalance) while it is still under the first rebalance process.

The following error messages in your stacktrace indicate that you are actually running into the problem I described above:

> ```
> Exception in thread "StreamThread-1" org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Failed to rebalance
> at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:299)
> at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:218)
> Caused by: org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.ProcessorStateException: Error while creating the state manager
> ```

The problem is summarized in this Apache Kafka ticket:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-3758

A recent change to the underlying Kafka consumer client fixes this issue:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-62%3A+Allow+consumer+to+send+heartbeats+from+a+background+thread

However it is not included in an official Kafka release yet and, as of today, is available only in Apache Kafka `trunk`.  If you are able to run your app with Kafka `trunk` you can verify if this problem has gone away already.

Answer (score 3):

I also saw this problem when the user didn't have permissions to write to the default state.dir

When I changed the following property to a dir w/good permissions everything was fine:

property.put(StreamsConfig.STATE_DIR_CONFIG, "{goodDir}")

This was observed in 0.10.2

Answer (score 1):

Just a note for those who receives the same `Failed to lock the state directory` exception and uses `The Spring for Apache Kafka (spring-kafka)` ([example from spring doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.1.8.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_kafka_streams_example)):

It took me a while to figure out in the source code that Spring starts your built Steams automatically, so there is no need for you to do manually something like:

```
KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder, config);
streams.start();
```

I dit it and faced the aforementioned exception because, not surpassingly, there were two Application instances running: one is created by Spring, another by me

Comment: Then how should we configure topology for Processor API without starting the stream manually?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly, but maybe [KafkaStreamsInfrastructureCustomizer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/config/KafkaStreamsInfrastructureCustomizer.html) is what you're looking for if you need to configure Topology before creating the stream